# How exactly should the input file be formatted for the language model finetuning (BERT through Huggingface Transformers)?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I wanted to employ the `examples/run_lm_finetuning.py` from the [Huggingface Transformers repository](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) on a pretrained Bert model. However, from following the documentation it is not evident how a corpus file should be structured (apart from referencing the Wiki-2 dataset). I've tried

- One document per line (multiple sentences)
- One sentence per line. Documents are separated by a blank line (this I found in some older pytorch-transformers documentation)

By looking at the code of `examples/run_lm_finetuning.py` it is not directly evident how sequence pairs for the Next Sentence Prediction objective are formed. Would the `--line-by-line` option help here? I'd be grateful, if someone could give me some hints how a text corpus file should look like.

Many thanks and cheers,

nminds

Answer (score 13):

First of all, I strongly suggest to also open this as an issue in the huggingface library, as they have probably the strongest interest to answer this, and may take it as a sign that they should update/clarify their documentation.

But to answer your question, it seems that this specific sample script is basically returning either a `LineByLineTextDataset` (if you pass `--line_by_line` to the training), and otherwise a `TextDataset`, see ll. 144-149 in [the script](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/run_lm_finetuning.py#L144) (formatted slightly for better visibility):

```py
def load_and_cache_examples(args, tokenizer, evaluate=False):
    file_path = args.eval_data_file if evaluate else args.train_data_file
    if args.line_by_line:
        return LineByLineTextDataset(tokenizer, args, 
                           file_path=file_path, block_size=args.block_size)
    else:
        return TextDataset(tokenizer, args, 
                           file_path=file_path, block_size=args.block_size)
```

A `TextDataset` simply splits the text into consecutive "blocks" of certain (token) length, e.g., it will cut your text every 512 tokens (default value).

The Next Sentence Prediction task is only implemented for the default BERT model, if I recall that correctly (seems to be consistent with what I found in [the documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertfornextsentenceprediction)), and is unfortunately not part of this specific finetuning script.
None of the utilized BERT models in the `lm_finetuning` script make use of that particular task, as far as I can see.

Comment: Good point, thank you - I'll take it to the issues as well. According to [this](https://github.com/rusiaaman/pytorch-transformers/tree/master/examples/lm_finetuning) training on both masked language and next sentence prediction objectives were possible although you could only use a set of default base Bert models. Loading your own pretrained model from disk isn't provided it seems.

Comment: Exactly, if you're only using BERT, this is perfectly fine (although I can't find any implementations on the fly), but most of the current code is written in a way to also support RoBERTa, XLM, etc.

Comment: @dennlinger I have 2 questions if you can answer. 1) What approach would be better? 2) I should make a text file of corpus, with one document in a line? what if a document is longer than 512?

Comment: Personally, I would always prefer to use a line-by-line approach, since you then have clear (semantic) differences between lines, since splitting at arbitrary points does not guarantee that a sentence actually finishes. For 2), I have rarely seen sentences that contain more than 512 tokens, otherwise I would split them in half, or proceed with the blocking strategy...

Comment: Side remark on the word "cut": the TextDataset class does not cut the text in such a way that a word might get split in halves. Instead, this is just the way the text file reads the bytes. I misunderstood that at first, but now I know that truncation can only be set with code like (see [Huggingface - Transformers - Fine-tune a pretrained model - Prepare a dataset](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#prepare-a-dataset)):

Comment: `from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")


def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)


tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)`,